# PHP Not Loaded on CentOS 7/Apache

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php7

I've installed `PHP 7.2.11` on my CentOS 7 VPS along with Apache; however, I can't seem to load the PHP module into Apache so that my server can serve PHP content.

Right now, if I go to a URL that should serve PHP content, it's just displays the plain PHP code.

My `httpd.conf` looks for modules under `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`. In that directory, `15-php.conf` has the following statement to load the required PHP module for Apache:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
```

Naturally, I restarted `httpd` to have it acknowledge the changes but with no luck.

What am I seem to be missing?

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. Thanks. Could you write it as an answer rather than a comment so that I can accept it. Also another question, as a best practice, should I add that statement directly into `httpd.conf` or into the php module file? @RuiFRibeiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of LAMP showing PHP files on the clear, upon new installations, or when migrating Apache configurations is fairly known.

Apache often does not know the mime type of the php file(s)/script(s), and thinks they are pure text files, and handles them as such.

Apache has them to be told the mime type of the intended extension name is `application/x-httpd-php php`

As for activating it, you might have the mime module for Apache; the configuration file usually is `/etc/httpd/mods-available/mime.conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/mime.conf`. (have not checked it out yet)

Lacking that file/module, I would prefer to add it to `httpd.conf`.

I would prefer not to touch `15-php.conf` as it might get updated with new versions of PHP.

So to get Apache to recognize .php files as scripts, it needs to be added:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

Comment: The directory for CentOS 7 is `conf.modules.d`. But I didn't have a `mime.conf` file anywhere so I created one named `00-mime.conf`. Also, what does that numbering scheme relate to before the conf files?

Comment: It is the order into which they are loaded. It is a convention followed in more Linux software that works with modules.

Comment: Then is it appropriate for `mime.conf` to be `00-mime.conf`?

Comment: It it is working for you, I see no problem.